# How to make excel know " " = "_" with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, search

I have a simple table like this.

[image]

And after I search "abc_d" in "B5" it will show up like this

[image]

I want every time I search for "abc d" or "abcd" in the "B5". It will also understand that I'm looking for "abc_d".

This is my code in VBA for searching value by filtering column

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    With Sheet1
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("A6:B6")
            .AutoFilter
            If Len(Range("A5").Value) <> 0 Then
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & Range("A5").Value & "*"
            End If
            If Len(Range("B5").Value) <> 0 Then
                .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & Range("B5").Value & "*"
            End If
        End With
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Is "_" the only special case?

Comment: Yes.  only " _ "

Answer (score 3):

### Autofilter After Replacing Specific Character

```vb
Dim bVal As String: bVal = CStr(Range("B5").Value)

If Len(bVal) > 0 Then
    bVal = Replace(bVal, " ", "")
    If Len(bVal) = 4 Then
        bVal = Left(bVal, 3) & "_" & Right(bVal, 1)
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & bVal & "*"
    End If
End If
```

i.e.

[image]

```vb
Sub Test()
    
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A7").CurrentRegion
        
        .Worksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
        
        Dim bVal As String: bVal = CStr(Range("B5").Value)
        
        If Len(bVal) <> 0 Then
            bVal = Replace(bVal, " ", "")
            If Len(bVal) = 4 Then
                bVal = Left(bVal, 3) & "_" & Right(bVal, 1)
                .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & bVal & "*"
            End If
        End If

    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but i want whenever i type in "abc d" or "abcd" in B5. Excel will know that i want to show every value with "abc_d". When i run your code. Hmm, seem like nothing happen when i search in b5

Comment: Did you adjust the range to your needs?

Comment: Yes i replace A7 => A6 from my table

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you could give your A5 value to a function that will give you an array back with either only the value or the value and the value with the " " replaced with "_".

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
         With .Range("A6:B6")
              .AutoFilter
              Dim arr
              If Len(Range("A5").Value) <> 0 Then
                 arr = replaceArray("*" & Range("A5").Value & "*")
                 .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
              End If
              If Len(Range("B5").Value) <> 0 Then
                 arr = replaceArray("*" & Range("B5").Value & "*")
                 .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
              End If
         End With
    End With
End Sub

Function replaceArray(val) As Variant()
    Dim arr
    If InStr(val, " ") > 0 Then
        ReDim arr(1 To 2)
        arr(1) = val
        arr(2) = Replace(val, " ", "_")
    ElseIf
        ReDim arr(1 To 1)
        arr(1) = val
    End If
    replaceArray = arr
End Function
```

Bit hardcoded but should do the job, could give the functions more possible arguments if you wanted to give it more of an all-around use.
Let me know if you've got questions.

**Edit:** It appears I misunderstood the question, suppose it's not " " -> "_" but always _ without it looking for both. Go with vBasic's solution then.